# Ошибка перевода строки даты и времени в объект класса QDateTime

Tags: c++, linux, qt, datetime, timestamp

Код

```
QDateTime::fromString("2018-Jun-20 13:14:02", "yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

возвращает невалидный объект.
Почему так? С локалями проблема какая-то?

Comment: Проблема в локали, поменяйте `Jun` на `Июн`, заработает

Comment: А если без этого, то как? Данных то много

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно указать локаль напрямую и конвертировать ей, как-то так:

```
QLocale locale(QLocale::English, QLocale::UnitedStates);
QDateTime dt = locale.toDateTime("2018-Jun-20 13:14:02", "yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: Добавлю, что несколько удобней будет использовать `QLocale::c()` вместо того чтобы привязываться к en_US.